# How to install conan and use it？

Tags: conan

Check if Conan is not installed correctly.install failed,The initial installation is through the PIP installation

1、pip install conan
2、conan
An error occurs at step 2（windows 7）

failed create aprocess

Answer (score 0):

There is a good page in Conan docs about [installation](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/installation.html).

The recommended way is using [pip](https://pypi.org/project/conan/)

If you are running Windows, please read carefully the notes in installation page.

Anyway, your problem is listed in [troubleshooting](https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/faq/troubleshooting.html#error-failed-to-create-process) page, where there is an explanation how to solve it.

Regards